# QGIS: How to export Coordinates of Polylines of a Layer (containing several Features) into single CSV-files?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, export, coordinates

Assumed we have some `shapefiles` imported into `QGIS`. Each `shapefile` consists of several `features`, in this case these are partly connected fragments of `polylines` (= streets with nodes). Now I want to export the line coordinates of each feature into a single `CSV` file.

---

**Example:**

Layer 1 ("highways") includes feature 1 (= street 1), feature 2 (= street 2), feature 3 (= street 3), feature 4 (= street 4), etc. while some features are connected to each other (e.g. end of street 3 to beginning of street 4).

**Question:**

So, how can I auto-export all features of the selected layer into single `CSV-files` *without the need* to do so for each single feature by itself?

Of course it would be possible to manually select each feature one by one, export it into the target `CSV` and go ahead to the next. Unfortunately, this would be a big workload in case of higher amounts of features per layer. :-)

---

In best case I would prefer to select the parental layer, choose "export all features of this layer into single `CSV` files (named with attributes ID)", and its done.

Comment: Right-click the layer - Export - Save features as, and choose csv

Comment: @MrXsquared: You are right! I mixed it up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip parts of this answer as you need / do not need them.

First you can add specific coordinates you want to your attribute table. Such as

- `x(start_point($geometry))` for the x coordinate of your startpoint
- `y(end_point($geometry))` for the y coordinate of the endpoint
- `geom_to_wkt(centroid($geometry))` for the wkt representation of the centroid
- `x(line_interpolate_point($geometry,length($geometry)/2)) || ',' || y(line_interpolate_point($geometry,length($geometry)/2))` for comma-separated x and y coordinates of the lines midpoint
- `array_to_string(array_foreach(generate_series(0,num_points($geometry)-1),x_at(@element)),',')` for a comma-separated "array" of all x coordinates of all nodes of the line
- ...

Now right-click your layer and go to Export -> Save features as...

[image]

Choose "CSV" as output, remove or add fields as you want and choose all other settings as you need them. Then scroll down a little to "Layer Options" and select "As WKT" as "Geometry". This will add a [WKT-Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) of your line to each feature.

[image]

You will get a CSV with all features, attributes and a geometry representation, for example:

```
WKT,id,name,attribute_midpoint_x_y
"LINESTRING (-1.42397137745975 0.141323792486583,-1.16636851520572 0.338103756708408,-0.765652951699463 0.180679785330948,-0.447227191413238 0.216457960644007,-0.178890876565295 0.449016100178891)","1",streat,"-0.8024987253833709,0.19515491070676894"
"LINESTRING (0.075134168157424 0.305903398926655,0.29695885509839 0.277280858676208,0.432915921288014 0.073345259391771,0.450805008944544 -0.094812164579607,0.543828264758497 -0.166368515205725,0.822898032200358 -0.177101967799642,1.10554561717352 -0.0304114490161,1.21645796064401 0.223613595706619)","2",precipitous,"0.6036208068122201,-0.16866822836163697"
"LINESTRING (1.21645796064401 0.223613595706619,1.22361359570662 0.363148479427549,1.1520572450805 0.481216457960644,1.04472271914132 0.584973166368515,0.89087656529517 0.68515205724508,0.783542039355993 0.728085867620751,0.704830053667263 0.756708407871199)","3",undersheets,"1.060582841445665,0.569641714807652"
"LINESTRING (0.704830053667263 0.756708407871199,0.347048300536673 0.788908765652952,0.075134168157424 0.749552772808587,-0.025044722719141 0.68515205724508,-0.189624329159213 0.635062611806798,-0.236135957066189 0.574239713774597,-0.175313059033989 0.524150268336315,-0.178890876565295 0.449016100178891)","4",prelims,"0.13068903580451594,0.7575936089154027"
"LINESTRING (-0.200357781753131 0.223613595706619,-0.293381037567084 0.091234347048301,-0.329159212880143 -0.091234347048301,-0.304114490161002 -0.155635062611807,-0.225402504472272 -0.24865831842576,-0.13953488372093 -0.341681574239714,-0.010733452593918 -0.384615384615385,0.110912343470483 -0.40608228980322,0.289803220035778 -0.431127012522361,0.450805008944544 -0.441860465116279,0.640429338103757 -0.42397137745975)","5",additions,"-0.07954702831089408,-0.361677526043059"
"LINESTRING (-0.096601073345259 -0.148479427549195,-0.046511627906977 -0.04830053667263,-0.007155635062612 0.087656529516995,-0.021466905187836 0.230769230769231,-0.107334525939177 0.330948121645796,-0.143112701252236 0.338103756708408,-0.211091234347048 0.330948121645796,-0.282647584973166 0.277280858676208,-0.350626118067979 0.191413237924866,-0.432915921288014 0.087656529516995,-0.500894454382826 0.019677996422182,-0.762075134168157 -0.066189624329159,-1.01610017889088 -0.066189624329159,-1.12343470483005 -0.04830053667263,-1.17352415026834 -0.033989266547406)","6",Infiltrates,"-0.37713312472882354,0.1579913599611918"
"LINESTRING (-1.50268336314848 -0.087656529516995,-1.40250447227191 -0.237924865831843,-1.32021466905188 -0.280858676207513,-1.01967799642218 -0.255813953488372,-0.840787119856887 -0.191413237924866,-0.644007155635063 -0.24865831842576,-0.540250447227191 -0.48479427549195,-0.379248658318426 -0.570661896243292,-0.143112701252236 -0.570661896243292,0.23613595706619 -0.592128801431127,0.61180679785331 -0.62432915921288,0.81216457960644 -0.588550983899821,0.865831842576029 -0.409660107334526,0.694096601073345 -0.259391771019678,0.479427549194991 -0.202146690518784,0.343470483005367 -0.169946332737031,0.200357781753131 -0.041144901610018,0.186046511627907 0.066189624329159,0.118067978533095 0.162790697674419,0.050089445438283 0.259391771019678,-0.014311270125224 0.352415026833631,0.007155635062612 0.456171735241503,0.007155635062612 0.488372093023256)","7",unroping,"0.2955889864224265,-0.5972247753759473"
```