# QGIS: How to export Coordinates of Polylines in Scheme of Latitude/Longitude instead of (default) Longitude/Latitude?

Tags: qgis, export, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I want to export line coordinates of several features of a layer into a CSV file.

This is [easily possible](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411974/105181) with `Export` -> `Save Selected Features As...` and choosing `Geometry: AS_WKT`:

[image]

---

However, this approach will write the coordinates in the scheme of `Longitude Latitude` into the CSV file (e.g. `11.3307, 50.9829`), like seen below:

[image]

OpenStreetMap uses coordinates the other way around in scheme of `Lat/Long` (e.g. `50.9829, 11.3307`) - this is what I need.

**How can I export coordinates into the CSV in the way of `Latitude Longitude`?**

Comment: I would rather study how to make Leaflet or whatever you are using to read the WKT in lon-lat order because that is by far more common type of WKT. It seems to work fine for example here http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/. Please describe what OSM service you would like to use, OSM is a large ecosystem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's emphasis that it is a strange requirement...  CRS and axis order are tightly coupled, so the clean solution is to export and load the data using the **same** CRS.

That being said, you can create the (not anymore)Well-known-text using swapped coordinates using a virtual layer.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query.

```sql
select *, st_astext(SwapCoordinates(geometry)) as lat_long_text 
from myLayer
```

You can then export this new dynamic layer as CSV, omitting the geometry field.

[image]